# Custom Paging using a stored procedure with OData feed C# without Entity Framework

Tags: c#, pagination, asp.net-web-api2, odata, powerbi

I am wondering if anyone can help me, for some time now I have being trying to figure out how to implement custom paging in a OData feed (v4) Web API 2 to feed a power bi feed and having no success.

The data is derived from a database first, database and is a combination of 5 tables using joins, which makes it not suitable to use with Entity Framework  apart from being really slow with Entity Framework (45k of records out of one controller).

I have tried many different approaches from, setting the total amount of records to trick the framework and padding the paged results with empty members of the list, to the more basic example below. However I still can not the get client (Power BI) take the paged results correctly without returning an extremely large amount of records from the controller. Please see a simplified query and code, any help would be extremely welcome as there appears to be no clear examples of how to do this without using Entity Framework.

The below code works but I keep having variants of the same problem the framework is doing the paging on the list after it returns, despite whatever I do before that

T-SQL Stored Procedure :

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetOrders] @CompanyID int,
                                   @Skip INT,
                                   @Take INT
AS

BEGIN 

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT *
FROM Orders 
WHERE CompanyID = @CompanyID
ORDER BY t.OrderID
OFFSET @Skip ROWS FETCH NEXT @Take  ROWS ONLY

END
```

The controller which points to a repo which calls the above query

```c#
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<PageResult<Order>> GetOrders(ODataQueryOptions<Order> queryOptions)
{
    int CompanyID = User.Identity.GetCompanyID().TryParseInt(0);

    ODataQuerySettings settings = new ODataQuerySettings()
    {
        PageSize = 100,
    };

    int OrderCount = _OrderRepo.GetOrderCount(CompanyID);
    int Skip = 0;

    if (queryOptions.Skip != null)
    {
        Skip =  queryOptions.Skip.Value;
    }

    IEnumerable<Order> results = await _OrderRepo.GetAll(CompanyID, Skip, 100);

    IQueryable result = queryOptions.ApplyTo(results.AsQueryable(), settings);

    Uri uri = Request.ODataProperties().NextLink;
    Request.ODataProperties().TotalCount =  OrderCount;

    PageResult<Order> response = new PageResult<Order>(
    result as IEnumerable<Order>,
    uri, Request.ODataProperties().TotalCount);

    return response;
}
```

The paging by the framework is done after this point `return response;`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `OFFSET` and `FETCH` for the SQL Query?

Comment: @MarkC. No particular reason,  I could also use OFFSET and FETCH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found in the end was to interrupt the framework by extending EnableQueryAttribute (Assuming you turn off filtering etc. and set max page size). In the paging query you need to go one above your page to fire an internal mechanism, this solution is just a workaround. The key is to set the Take to 0 before you "ApplyTo".

```
IEnumerable<Order> results = await _OrderRepo.GetAll(CompanyID, Skip, Take + 1);
```

PagingAttribute

```
public sealed class PagingAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    public override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        var result = default(IQueryable);
        var originalRequest = queryOptions.Request;

        var skip = queryOptions.Skip == null ? 0 : queryOptions.Skip.Value;
        var take = queryOptions.Top == null ? PageSize : queryOptions.Top.Value;

        queryOptions = ODataQueryOptionsUtilities.Transform(queryOptions, new ODataQueryOptionsUtilitiesTransformSettings { Skip = (map, option) => default(int?) });

        if (queryOptions.Request.ODataProperties().TotalCount != null)
            originalRequest.ODataProperties().TotalCount = originalRequest.GetInlineCount();

        result = queryOptions.ApplyTo(queryable);

        if (skip + take <= originalRequest.ODataProperties().TotalCount)
            originalRequest.ODataProperties().NextLink = NextPageLink.GetNextNewPageLink(originalRequest, (skip + take));

        return result;
    }
}
```

I set the below in the controller

```
        originalRequest.ODataProperties().TotalCount = Query.Item1; // Total size of all records to be returned
        originalRequest.SetInlineCount(Query.Item1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your full requirements, I'm going to assume the ultimate destination of this data will be a Power Bi report.  With that, I suggest you skip the special paging code altogether and let Power Bi desktop connect directly to the SQL Server to access the tables.

Power Bi desktop will do its best to re-create the relationships for you.  If your original tables and ids were named in a strait forward manner, Power Bi desktop does a quite decent job of recreating the relationships for you.  Give it a try.

Once the import is complete, you are able check the relationships when you [click on the Relationship View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-relationship-view).  If a relationship is wrong, double-click on it to remove or edit.

If your fear is that each time the report is run, you will be hurting the performance of the database, the default mode for Power Bi is to import a copy of the data.  This is recommended if the data is less than 1GB.

For larger data sets, there is a [DirectQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-use-directquery) option that can be tried.  DirectQuery was developed in response to a need to load larger data sets and has its limitations (single source database, cant handle overly complex queries, , database performance, and some visuals are limited in features).

Comment: For security reasons I can not allow Power Bi to connect directly to the db and it is not a single client db.

Comment: silly question:  is there a requirement for your Power Bi report to page through your data set?  If not and your data set is less than 1GB, I still recommend you use the import option to your ODATA feed without pagination.

Comment: The data set is too large to loaded in the manner that web api2 odata paging does it out of the box, getting all the data in one go then paging it, apart from returning only the requested amount. This is extremely wasteful when dealing with many large tables one go. Where it is pulling more than one table at at a time.

Comment: Have you tried to look at using parameters in Power BI and custom functions to invoke those parameters? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iiNDq2VrZPY